# Zen Cart update database with Post affiliate pro id

Tags: php, zen-cart

We are in the process of creating a specialty cart where our when a client makes a purchase it logs the Affiliate id in the database at time of purchase. I have created the following code to get the affiliate id/name using the Post Affiliate Pro API.

```
include ("affiliate/api/PapApi.class.php");
$session = new Gpf_Api_Session("https://www.elitespecialtymeats.com/affiliate/scripts/server.php"); 
if(!$session->login("user", "password")){ die("Cannot login. Message: ".$session->getMessage()); }
$clickTracker = new Pap_Api_ClickTracker($session);
try {
    $clickTracker->track();
    $clickTracker->saveCookies();
    if ($clickTracker->getAffiliate() != null){ $affid=$clickTracker->getAffiliate()->getValue('username'); }
    else{ $affid=''; }
}catch (Exception $e){
    $affid='';
}
```

I am trying to figure out the best way of adding that id into the purchase. I think it may be best to add it in tpl_checkout_success_default.php where they log the purchase into PAP. My issue is that I dont know enough about the system to implement the code.

My best guess is

```
 $db->Execute("UPDATE ".TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL." SET affid='$affid' where orders_id = '".(int)$orders->fields['orders_id']."' AND class in ('ot_coupon', 'ot_gv', 'ot_subtotal', 'ot_group_pricing', 'ot_quantity_discount')");
```

Will this work or will i mess something up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, using the API you are loading affiliate username ( ...getValue('username') ), not affiliate ID as you stated in the first paragraph. You should use getValue('userid'); (for affiliate ID) or getValue('refid'); (for referral ID).

The database command you are trying to use will only work in case the the table TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL has a column called 'affid'. You can add it manually to the table...

I am wondering why are you doing something like this... It seems like you want to use the ID for some special purpose later. Do you want to give a commission to the original referring person even the customer removed all the cookies or clicked another affiliate's banner meanwhile? If so, you should use Lifetime commissions instead:
http://support.qualityunit.com/541587-Lifetime-commissions

In case you need any other help, feel free to contact our online support.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the way JROX does it - they are an affiliate marketing system that is popular with Zen Cart.  It's described here: http://jam.jrox.com/docs/index.php?article=111

Basically they just piggyback onto the checkout success page and stick their logic in the footer.